# Vuejs Reactive propery interpolation is not working

Tags: vue.js, properties, reactive

I've run into an issue where i'm creating components that are then being applied to the root App - after creating a dynamic child w/ vanilla JS. When i look at the Vue object in the console, message is not present, which i expect it to be - Can anyone tell me why?

- Create the App
- Dynamically add new DOM element w/ `createElement` with a {{ message }} property (ex: `<div id="test">{{message}}</div>`)
- Create a custom component using Vue.Component (ex: `<custom-component><custom-component>` w/ pre-populated `{{ messsage }}` value test message
- Render the Vue w/ the component w/ update props values for `{{ message }}`

Below is the actual code tested:

```js
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js';
export default {
  name: 'app',
  components:
  {
    HelloWorld
  },
  data()
  {
    return this;
  },
  mounted()
  {

    // #2 Create an Html Target that contains the component's name 'custom-element'
    var v = document.createElement('div');
      v.setAttribute('id', 'test');
      v.innerHTML = '<custom-element></custom-element>';
    var $element = this.$el.prepend(v);

    // #1 Create a component
    var MyComponent = Vue.component(
      'custom-element',
      {
        template: '<div v-bind:id="UID">{{message}}</div>',
        prop: ['UUID', 'message'],
        data() {
          return {
            UID: '',
            message: 'test message',
          }
        },
      }
    );

    // #3 Append the component to the Html Target
    window.vm = new Vue({
        el: '#test',
        components: {
          'custom-component': MyComponent,
        },
        beforeCreate() {
          return {
            UID: 'x7x7x',
            message: 'test message update...'
          }
        },
    })

    window.console.log(MyComponent);
    window.console.log(this);
  }
}`
```

Here's the main index.html:

```js
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
    <title>hello-world</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but hello-world doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>'
```

Here's the main.js

```js
'use strict'

import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import Reaktr from './js/reaktr.js'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
  data: {
    Reaktr: new Reaktr(),
  },
  mounted() {

  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

Here's the Helloworld.vue

```js
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: {
    msg: String
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I even tried adding data() { return { message: '' }} to the original app data function, which then shows the 'message' getter/setter in the Vue object, but it still will not update the message.

Comment: please provide the template html content

Comment: eNot understanding, you mean the index.html file? The `custom-element` component has the `template`. Here's the HTML output: `<div id="app"><div id="test"><div id="">test message</div></div></div>`

Comment: the `custom-element`

Comment: That template is in the sample code above as `template: '<div v-bind:id="UID">{{message}}</div>'`

Comment: there's some things in your code that i don't understand in your code like `data()
  {
    return this;
  }` and where's the `HelloWorld` component?

Comment: The Helloworld is another component is harcoded in separate .vue that loads and works fine. I need to be able to create dynamic components and place them anywhere a user might wish in the layout. I'll post those above. The data return this was just a test, it is no longer in and still was not hindering/helping. I posted the additional code for you.

Comment: I found that the it's located here `window.vm.$children[0].message = 'Joe'` as this changed the value, just still new to Vue so not sure how to handle event/change scope in these scenarios. Also, i can't find HelloWorlds' 'msg' data yet.

Comment: where you put the first code ?

Comment: i see that you have created two vue instances

Comment: The index.html creates the main `#app` placeholder. `main.js` loads and renders the app w/ `App.vue`. The main export in `App.Vue calls` and renders `HelloWorld.vue`. In the `App.vue` mounted calback, i'm trying to load additional custom component into the App.vue perview using Vue.component. How can i do this and have the iterpolation work

Comment: what are the generated errors?

Comment: There are no error, it just doesn't work. The console is free of errors

Comment: the `app.vue` contains only the first code snippet?

Comment: Yes. I was able to add a Vue.extend({...}) + $mount() - but i think i read somewhere that's not the way they want you to do it.

Comment: i understand that in your `app.vue` you don't wrap your code with `<script>...</script>` tags?